# pmdarima assign object to auto_arima output

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, statsmodels, pmdarima

I am experimenting with auto_arima which gives a nice output of the best model to use for a time series prediction.

`from pmdarima import auto_arima`

```
stepwise_fit = auto_arima(hourly_avg['kW'], start_p=0, start_q=0,
                          max_p=2, max_q=2, m=4,
                          seasonal=False,
                          d=None, trace=True,
                          error_action='ignore',   # we don't want to know if an order does not work
                          suppress_warnings=True,  # we don't want convergence warnings
                          stepwise=True)           # set to stepwise

stepwise_fit.summary()
```

Output:

```
Performing stepwise search to minimize aic
 ARIMA(0,0,0)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=778.328, Time=0.01 sec
 ARIMA(1,0,0)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=inf, Time=0.07 sec
 ARIMA(0,0,1)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=inf, Time=0.07 sec
 ARIMA(1,0,1)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=138.016, Time=0.12 sec
 ARIMA(2,0,1)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=135.913, Time=0.16 sec
 ARIMA(2,0,0)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=inf, Time=0.11 sec
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=135.302, Time=0.27 sec
 ARIMA(1,0,2)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=138.299, Time=0.14 sec
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=121.020, Time=0.36 sec
 ARIMA(1,0,2)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=123.032, Time=0.36 sec
 ARIMA(2,0,1)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=119.824, Time=0.28 sec
 ARIMA(1,0,1)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=125.968, Time=0.31 sec
 ARIMA(2,0,0)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=118.512, Time=0.15 sec
 ARIMA(1,0,0)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=130.956, Time=0.12 sec

Best model:  ARIMA(2,0,0)(0,0,0)[0] intercept
Total fit time: 2.547 seconds
```

There's not alot of wisdom here which I apologize for but is it possible to assign a variable to the best fit model? OR does one have to manually select `ARIMA(2,0,0)` from the output above to continue on with their time series prediction methods?

For example some variable like `best_model = Best model:  ARIMA(2,0,0)` what ever the best selection is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Look at the documentation where they give an example](https://pypi.org/project/pmdarima/):

```
model = pm.auto_arima(train, seasonal=False)

# make your forecasts
forecasts = model.predict(24)  # predict N steps into the future
```